# Android: Use ProgressBar within ProgresDialog

Tags: android, android-progressbar

I am using this library which extends ProgressBar. (https://github.com/ylyc/circular_progress_bar)

How can I use it within a ProgressDialog.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement AlertDialog with custom layout.

Please take a look for an example here: [How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13342157/1235698)

Comment: The class in which I write   setContentView(R.layout.progressbar) is already extended as fragment. And I want to increase the progress in run time. I cant extend dialog and fragment together.

Comment: @MJ123 You can create new layout file which has plain FrameLayout, then in runtime phase, you just need to use FragmentTransaction to add your fragment programmatically like this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20455416/programmatically-adding-fragment-to-framelayout-in-android

Comment: Now it will show up as a fragment right. How can I show this fragment within a progress dialog.

Comment: As I said, you have to create layout file with plain FrameLayout, use it as custom dialog box's layout, then add that fragment into it programmatically

Please take a look at above links and combine them together :D